# Why IntelliJ doesn't run my script if it has main in it

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am observing an interesting behavior. I have an existing project in which I created a folder and created a `Scala` script in that folder. To run it I did

1. Write a Scala script, e.g. MyScript.scala
2. In the menu select: Run ->    Edit Configurations... Press the "+" (⌘N also works on the Mac in    this dialog) Select "Scala Script" Then select your Script file in    this dialog

Interestingly, if the script is the following then I get error `Scala script not found`

```
object HelloWorld{

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
    println("hello world");
  }
}
```

but if the script is

```
def greetings(): Unit ={
  println("hello")
}


greetings();
```

then it works!

Why `IntelliJ` cannot run the 1st version of the script?

Comment: Can you please look into this it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600131/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-classes-scripts-and-worksheets-in-intellij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

**Run it as a script**. 
You have to use the following code:

```
class HelloWorld {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
    println("hello world");
  }
}    
object Foo extends HelloWorld
Foo.main(args)
```

[image]

Hint: I removed the 'build' action from 'Before launch' to show the warnings further down.

**Run it as an Application**. 
You can keep your code. Just select 'Application' when creating the configuration.

```
object HelloWorld{

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
    println("hello world");
  }
}
```

[image]

**Why?**

You have to provide an entry point for the script. So you could use the following code:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
    println("hello world");
  }
}
HelloWorld.main(args) //without this line, Script is not found!
```

But this gives an error (expected class or object definition):

[image]

An If you try to extend from App trait, you get 2 warnings:

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  override def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
    println("hello world");
  }
}
HelloWorld.main(args)
```

[image]

So I guess its best to use one of two Solutions above.